Cmake if condition (directory existence) in add_custom_target fails in some builds?
I have seen CMake: how to use if condition in add_custom_command(...) - but I simply cannot get the following to work: in add_custom_target,  heck for an existence of a directory, if it does not exist, output message - which I try to implement as a bash one-liner.
The strange thing is that I cannot reproduce this error on a PC - only on a Raspberry Pi, with custom-built cmake-3.28.1:
$ uname -a
Linux raspberry 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l

Here is an example CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(ProjectName)

SET(OPT_DEBS "/opt/debs")
add_custom_target(check_opt_debs
  ALL
  COMMENT "Checking for existence of ${OPT_DEBS} directory"
  COMMAND /bin/bash -c "[ ! -d '${OPT_DEBS}' ] && echo 'Directory ${OPT_DEBS} DOES NOT exist; please run \\`sudo mkdir /opt/debs\\` to create it, before running \\`make package\\`/\\`cpack\\` !!'"
)

Then I run like this:
$ /home/pi/src/cmake-3.28.1/bin/cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (2.1s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp

... and when I run make, I get:
/bin/sh: 1:  echo Directory\ /opt/debs\ DOES\ NOT\ exist;\ please\ run\ \`sudo\ mkdir\ /opt/debs\`\ to\ create\ it,\ before\ running\ \`make\ package\`/\`cpack\`\ !!: not found
CMakeFiles/check_opt_debs.dir/build.make:70: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/check_opt_debs' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/check_opt_debs] Error 127
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/check_opt_debs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/check_opt_debs.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

I thought I had escaped everything correctly (and indeed, this snippet does not fail when ran on a cmake on a computer) - why would it fail here?

Had to escape the damned ampersands & with two backslashes \\, and the semicolon ; with one backslash \ - and then it works (don't ask me why).
Corrected CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(ProjectName)

SET(OPT_DEBS "/opt/debs")
add_custom_target(check_opt_debs
  ALL
  COMMENT "Checking for existence of ${OPT_DEBS} directory"
  COMMAND /bin/bash -c "[ ! -d '${OPT_DEBS}' ] \\&\\& echo 'Directory ${OPT_DEBS} DOES NOT exist\; please run \\`sudo mkdir /opt/debs\\` to create it, before running \\`make package\\`/\\`cpack\\` !!'" # works
)

And here is the result when it works:
$ make
[100%] Checking for existence of /opt/debs directory
Directory /opt/debs DOES NOT exist; please run `sudo mkdir /opt/debs` to create it, before running `make package`/`cpack` !!
[100%] Built target check_opt_debs

